# How to get Marketo Form element's values in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, marketo

I have the marketo script

```
<script src="//app-abba.marketo.com/js/forms2/js/forms2.min.js"> </script> 
       <form id="mktoForm_id1"> </form> 
    <script>MktoForms2.loadForm("//app-aba.marketo.com", "xxx-XXX-xxx", id1);  </script>
```

Placing it in PHP\Worpress displays all the Marketo fields along with the Submit button.

### **My Requirement**

But before Submitting the Marketo Form

1. I want to get the form elements values
2. Do some calculation with the values
3. Display the result on click of Marketo Submit Button.

Please give me details on how to implement this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this example.

This code will capture the form fields upon a successful form submission.

(Make sure you use your form's embed code)

```js
<script src="//xxxxx.marketo.com/js/forms2/js/forms2.min.js"></script>
<form id="mktoForm_1"></form>
<script>
    MktoForms2.loadForm("//app-sjqe.marketo.com", "123-ABC-456", 1, function(form) {
        form.onSubmit(function() {
            var vals = form.vals();
            console.log(vals);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. this capture form values.
Is it possible to have an ajax call  
like
<script>
    MktoForms2.loadForm("//aqq-abc.marketo.com", "xxx-XXX-xxx", id1, function(form) {
        form.onSubmit(function() {
         var vals = form.vals();
         $.ajax({
                        type: "POST", 
                        url: "http://localhost:3422/calM/new_generate.php",
                  success: function( data ) {
                alert(data);
              },
  error:  function( err ) {alert("Error.");}
 });
  });
    });
</script>

Comment: I mean to send the marketo form data to another php in ajaxCall like  ============>
MktoForms2.loadForm("//aqq-abc.marketo.com", "xxx-XXX-xxx", id1, function(form) { form.onSubmit(function() { var vals = form.vals(); $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "localhost:3422/calM/new_generate.php";,
data: value1:val[0],value2:vals[1], success: function( data ) { alert(data); }, error: function( err ) {alert("Error.");} }); }); }); </script>

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to get all of the fields in the form and loop through them, using the `elements` property on the form.

Example:

```
var form = document.getElementById('mktoForm_id1');

console.log(form.elements); // contains all form fields.
```

Add a `submit` event listener to catch the values of the form fields before submitting.

Comment: Thanks Enijar.
I am a newbie. I tried the as per your reply. Its firing before the displaying the Marketo form elements on the page.
Where should I place the script to get the desired effect (make calculation with form values)


<form id="mktoForm_id1"></form>
<script>
    MktoForms2.loadForm("//app-aba.marketo.com", "xxx-XXX-xxx", id1);
    MktoForms2.whenReady(function(form) {var form = document.getElementById(\'mktoForm_id1\');alert(document.getElementById("mktoForm_id1").elements.item(0).value);});

</script>